# pointwise convergence, bounded to unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

so im thinking of an example that takes a bounded function, which convergese pointwise to an unbounded function,

would $f_n : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ $f_n(x) = n/(1+nx) $ work? We have $f_n \to f$ where $f = 1/x$ (so unbounded) but $|f_n| < n$. Does this work, and can anyone think of smarter examples?

Comment: This works.  In general, you could just use any unbounded function like $f=1/x$ and consider a piecewise version: $f_n=1/x$ when $1/x<n$ and $n$ when $1/x\geq n$.  This is sometimes called a cut-off function.

Comment: Another idea I had, albeit perhaps more complex, is to take a function like $\tan(x)$, which has singularities at $x = k \pi/2$, and choose $f_n$ to be the $n$th partial sum of its Taylor series centered at, say, $x = 0$.